# how to divide each element in a list of lists by a number in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list 'q' and i want to divide each number in q by the sum in each list (=10)
I tried this:

```
q = [[0,0,0,10],[1,2,6,1]]
B=[]
for x in q:
    y = [z/sum(x[:len(x)]) for z in x]
    B.append(y)   
print B
```

It does not give me the expected result

anyone knows whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ python
>>> q = [[0,0,0,10],[1,2,6,1]]
>>> B = [[float(j)/sum(i) for j in i] for i in q]
>>> B
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1]]
```

**Note:** in `python3`, `float()` is not required.

Comment: I have `q = [[7,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and `r=[[6,1,2],[3,4,5]]`. I need to divide the corresponding elements. `B= [[float(j)/float(i) for j in q] for i in r]`. However, I keep getting an error : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number. I have imported division from future. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
B = []
for x in q:
   theSum = sum(x)
   y = [float(xi) / theSum for xi in x]
   B.append(y)
print B
```

Answer (score 2):

You're performing integer division, since both operands are integers.

```
y = [float(z)/sum(x) for z in x]
```

Comment: I have `q = [[7,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and `r=[[6,1,2],[3,4,5]]`. I need to divide the corresponding elements. `B= [[float(j)/float(i) for j in q] for i in r]`. However, I keep getting an error : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number. I have imported division from future. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, your program will use integer division, which seems not to be what you're looking for. Instead of converting one of the values explicitly to a float, however, I'll suggest that the right solution is to add `from ___future__ import division` to the top of your script (and, indeed, *every script* you write for Python versions before Python 3). This switches division to returning float values, which eliminates a lot of subtle math bugs. For those occasions where you do need integer division, you can use a double-slash `//`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using integer division, which will round the result to the next integer towards zero.  Convert one of the operands to `float` to get floating point division.  To do convert the array in place, you can do

```
for row in q:
    s = float(sum(row))
    row[:] = [x / s for x in row]
```